# How to read a formatted text file with some header, column names, and data?

Tags: pandas

I am essentially using pandas to read in a formatted text file with a header, column names, and data but I am unable to get the final product. I want the header info in a variable, the column names and data in a dataframe. What am I doing wrong here?

I have tried using `pandas.read_csv`...see below code. Here is the text file:

```
2018 IOWA Data Version A229033
Year Mon Day Jday  Hr Min    Rate  Lat        Lon
2018  01  08  008  16  45    3.05  38.07760  -75.55848
2018  01  08  008  16  46    3.05  38.07760  -75.55848
2018  01  08  008  16  47    3.05  38.07760  -75.55848
2018  01  08  008  16  48    3.05  38.07760  -75.55848
2018  01  08  008  16  49    3.05  38.07760  -75.55848
2018  01  08  008  20  25    3.05  38.07760  -75.55848
2018  01  08  008  20  26    3.05  38.07760  -75.55848
```

python

```
cols=['year', 'mon', 'day', 'jday', 'hr', 'min', 'rate', 'lat', 'lon']
data=pd.read_csv(file, names=cols, skiprows=1, header=None)
```

In the end, I want to be able to access each column and row in the format `data[year][0]`. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using `sep='\s+'`:  `data=pd.read_csv(a, sep= '\s+', names=cols, skiprows=1, header=None)`

Comment: Yes, this helps. But how do I get the header "2018 IOWA Data Version A229033" into a variable? My goal is to do some processing of the data and write back to a text file so I need to be able to paste the header info back into a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your file it shows that first row is the header and thereafter comes the dataframe.

in order to SKIP the first line (header) you should read it with the skiprows (credit to @Erfan from the comments):

```
data=pd.read_csv(a, sep= '\s+', names=cols, skiprows=1, header=None)
```

For the next part - reading the title only you can simply do something like this:

```
title = pd.read_csv(file, nrows=0,  usecols=[0])
title = title.columns.values[0]
```

Note that you only read the first line (nrows=2) of the csv file.

Result: **2018 IOWA Data Version A229033**

Comment: @Charanjit Pabla my pleasure.